# Syntax for Describing DFA or NFA

Tags: fsm, automata, state-machine, dfa, nfa

Do there exists any Standard Syntax for Describing the Transition Table for an NFA or DFA ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the GDL (Graph Description Language) to do this:

[Graph Description Language](http://www.aisee.com/gdl/nutshell/)

You may also be interested in DOT, which is a plain text graph description language: [DOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language)

Comment: The first link is dead